# SQL STDistance not calculating correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, geospatial, spatial

I would like to find the shortest distance of a point to a line, using the STDistance function turned out it is only calculating the the shortest distance to each point defined in the geometry, but this is obviously not correct as if there is a line and e.g 10meters and at the middle of it at distance 1 meter there is a point, the function will not return the correct distance of 1m but will get the shortest distance from the 2 ends of the line...

```
DECLARE @point geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT (6.0 1.0)',4135); 
DECLARE @line1 geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (1.0 1.0, 1.0 11.0)',4135)
DECLARE @line2 geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (1.0 4.0, 6.0 3.0, 11.0 4.0)',4135)

SELECT  @point.STDistance(@line1) as dist_to_line1
SELECT  @point.STDistance(@line2)as dist_to_line2
```

Result

```
distance to line 1 : 5
distance to line 2 : 2
```

Is there any way to get the actual shortest distance to a line or other shape?

Comment: Eh? The shortest distance from the point (6,1) to a point on the line (1,1) -> (1,11) *is* 5 units. Did you perhaps mix up the coordinates of the second point in that line? If you make the second line `'LINESTRING (1.0 1.0, 11.0 1.0)'` the result is 0. You might want to include `select @point.STUnion(@line1).STUnion(@line2)` in your sample and examine the Spatial Results tab to see that these returned results seem to be correct.

Comment: Similarly, `LINESTRING (1.0 2.0, 11.0 2.0)`, which matches your narrative example, returns 1.

Comment: You are right, I've got them mixed up! Thank you!